# React-native targetSDKVersion for Google Play Store Requirement

Tags: android, react-native, target-sdk

Google Play Store has announced that new apps target at least Android 9.0 (API level 28) starting August 1, 2019. 
Reference:https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk

I have updated my app targetSDKVersion to 28 in ./android/build.gradle and the app app can be run normally.

However, I found the targetSDKVersion for other react-native libraries I using are below 28, will it affect the app uploading to the Play Store?

Thanks.

Comment: Late follow up, have been successfully uploading the app regardless of the tragetSDKVersion fro other react-native libraries